# How to exit a runloop?

Tags: swift, swift3

So, I have a Swift command-line program:

```
import Foundation

print("start")

startAsyncNetworkingStuff()

RunLoop.current.run()

print("end")
```

The code compiles without error. The async networking code runs just fine, fetches all its data, prints the result, and eventually calls its completion function.

How do I get that completion function to break out of above current runloop so that the last "end" gets printed?

Added:

Replacing RunLoop.current.run() with the following:

```
print("start")

var shouldKeepRunning = true

startAsyncNetworkingStuff()

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
while (   shouldKeepRunning
       && runLoop.run(mode:   .defaultRunLoopMode,
                      before: .distantFuture ) ) {
}

print("end")
```

Setting

```
shouldKeepRunning = false
```

in the async network completion function still does not result in "end" getting printed.  (This was checked by bracketing the shouldKeepRunning = false statement with print statements which actually do print to console).  What is missing?

Comment: In the [`run` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrunloop/1412430-run?language=objc), they say "If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this [`run`] method. Instead, use one of the other `run` methods and also check other arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop." The subsequent example there is in Objective-C, but it illustrates the idea.

Comment: See update to question, as per the other suggested run method.  No change in "end" result.

Answer (score 16):

For a command line interface use this pattern and add a completion handler to your *AsyncNetworkingStuff* (thanks to Rob for code improvement):

```
print("start")

let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
startAsyncNetworkingStuff() { result in 
   CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
}

CFRunLoopRun()
print("end")
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

Please don't use ugly `while` loops.

---

**Update:**

In Swift 5.5+ with async/await it has become much more comfortable. There's no need anymore to maintain the run loop.

Rename the file `main.swift` as something else and use the `@main` attribute like in a normal application.

```
@main
struct CLI {

    static func main() async throws {
        let result = await startAsyncNetworkingStuff()
        // do something with result 
    }
}
```

The name of the struct is arbitrary, the static function `main` is mandatory and is the entry point.

Comment: Ugly?  But it's recommended in Apple's official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/runloop/1412430-run

Comment: Ugly. I guess the (Objective-C) documentation has been written (and never been revised) before the introduction of blocks ;-)

Comment: Halfway works.  Calling CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()) in a Timer callback function works ("end" prints).  But calling CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()) in an NSURLSession dataTask completion block does not seem to stop the CFRunLoop ("end" never prints).

Comment: I'm using exactly this code with URLSession in a CLI. @Rob The redundancy of stopping the run loop and calling `exit` could be, probably it's just the practice to leave the CLI with a certain state.

Comment: @vadian. I agree. That while loop was hella ugly. There's no need to to use parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to use `URLSession` in a macOS Command Line Tool using Swift 4.2

```
// Mac Command Line Tool with Async Wait and Exit
import Cocoa

// Store a reference to the current run loop
let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()

// Create a background task to load a webpage
let url = URL(string: "http://SuperEasyApps.com")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        print("Loaded: \(data) bytes")
    }
    // Stop the saved run loop
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
}
task.resume()

// Start run loop after work has been started
print("start")
CFRunLoopRun()
print("end") // End will print after the run loop is stopped

// If your command line tool finished return success,
// otherwise return EXIT_FAILURE
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

You'll have to call the stop function using a reference to the run loop before you started (as shown above), or using GCD in order to exit as you'd expect.

```
func stopRunLoop() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())
    }
}
```

**References**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542011-cfrunlooprun

> Run loops can be run recursively. You can call CFRunLoopRun() from within any run loop callout and create nested run loop activations on the current thread’s call stack.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1541796-cfrunloopstop

> If the run loop is nested with a callout from one activation starting another activation running, only the innermost activation is exited.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question)

Adding the following snippet to my async network completion code allows "end" to be printed :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    shouldKeepRunning = false
}
```

Comment: It looks like my original code had a threading bug in the inter-thread communication between the async networking thread and the main runloop thread.

Comment: Here's my final working code using solution #2: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/827a6e710d24036bdcb6a37aab921c6a#file-nsurl-dtask-test1-swift

Comment: It's much easier to use the URLSession API with completion handler rather than protocol/delegate.

Comment: @vadian : Example for a long running dataTask?  (it's for data from a very slow server where the data dribbles down over many seconds.)

Comment: That doesn't matter. The delegate methods are only useful if you need to handle credentials or display a progress bar.

Comment: A progress bar is important if the data download takes many seconds, minutes, hours; and/or partial data is useful (which is true in my case).